# timeout of 2000ms exceeded in mocha (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, mocha.js, integration-testing

I had `before` in my integration tests defined like this:

```
  let response = null
  before('read data', done => {
    request(
      {
        uri: 'some/endpoint'
      }
    ) 
    .then(resp => {
      response = fromJS(resp)
      done()
    })
    .catch(e => {
      done(e)
    })
  })
```

The tests were doing checks for content in the response and were passing perfectly fine on my machine and previously were also passing when I pushed on server. However, recently the tests on server started failing with `timeout of 2000ms exceeded` error. I am sure that the request takes less than 500ms, so this is really strange. After googling for a while and trying some suggestions, I found a workaround. This code works fine:

```
let response = null
  before('read data', async () => {
    response = fromJS(
      await Promise.resolve(
        request(
          {
            uri: 'some/endpoint'
          }

        )
      )
    )
  })
```

What I want to know is, what was the issue with my old approach? What was taking so much time for the request?

The error is:
`Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

Comment: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: Why the downvote? I ask why something that worked yesterday and in the last 6 months, doesn't work today. My code now works, but I am curious why the old tests are now broken.

Comment: Can you post the full error please ?

Comment: @SergeK. I edited my question

Comment: Maybe the fromJS call threw an error. You didn't catch it so the `done()` was never called. In the second approach, the async function caught the error since it wasn't in a callback.

Comment: **ensure "done()" is called**

Comment: @Serge K. I call it in both then and catch? Shouldn't that be enough? Or do I need to call it in finally?

Comment: The first code should work for sure. Did you put some `console.log` to see where you are just before the timeout?

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT No. But the strange thing is that it always works on my machine. I succeeded to make it fail on my machine by setting a lower timeout of 100ms and then I receive the same error I mentioned in my comment. But with the default of 2000 ms it never fails on my machine. Will try with some logs later.

Comment: hmm ok it seems that the performances are involved here. Because the server is less powerfull the test makes more time to run and sometimes timeout. What you can do is to increase the timeout to see if it's the right problem - `mocha -t 300000`